# The GridView does not update immediately after calling method notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to build Tic-Tac-Toe game( just for human play with android device, I have implemented a smart algorithm called minimax for my bot) by using android GridView. I have built everything successfully( UI, minimax algorithm for my bot) but there is still a hard to understand problem, that is when I click on Gridview item, I want GridView must update immediately, then my bot start it calculating.So, I have implement my code to set on GridView item click as followings:

```
gridviewBoard.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        //if it is a legal moves of player
        if (isLegal(false, i)){
            //put X into board
            put(false, i);
            //I want to update gridview immediately by using notifyDataSetChanged()
            chessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //then start my bot calculating
            // findBestMove is a method to find the best move for my bot 
            // by using minimax algorithm 
            int nextMove = findBestMove();
        }
    }
}
```

Howerver, the gridviewBoard did not update immediately, the gridviewBoard only updates when the findBestMove function is computed while it takes a long time to calculate. Summary, I want to update gridviewBoard immediately after item click and before my bot calculating. Can someone help me, and sorry for my bad English grammar.

Comment: Use a thread to do the checks and calculations.

Comment: You can move findBestMove to AsyncTask to process in background